# what to use to get DOC from string?

Tags: sql-server

i have to get a substring through sql query which should fetch 'DOC=some number' from my db record. 
I had tried all of the functions like charIndex, substring but i am not getting my required output.

The output should be like;

Doc=some_number (22333);
Doc=some_num(333)
.
.
.

```
.
select * from SMSReceived
where ReceivedId Between 29 and 40707;;


SELECT top 20 t.ReceivedId, SUBSTRING(s.MessageText,9,13) some_name 
FROM SMSReceived t inner join SMSReceived s on t.ReceivedId=s.ReceivedId
where s.ReceivedId Between 29 and 40707;
```

here is the query with screen shot below;

[image: Query Result]

Answer (score 0):

PATINDEX provides the first occurance of the specifed string.

```
    SELECT top 20 t.ReceivedId, SUBSTRING(s.MessageText,PATINDEX('%DOC%',s.MessageText),13) 
some_name 
    FROM SMSReceived t inner join SMSReceived s on t.ReceivedId=s.ReceivedId
    where s.ReceivedId Between 29 and 40707;
```